# three.js how to get scene by id(name)

Tags: three.js

I created a scene;
How can I get it by id(name)?
Like `jquery(#test)`?

In `three.js` doc,I just find the `scene.getObjectById()` to  get children obj.

Comment: do you want to get the scene ?

Comment: `//some code here.....create renderer,camera;  var scene=new THREE.Scene();  `
`scene.name="IWantName";  `
`scene.userData.someProp="testGetObjectByName";  `
`renderer.render( scene, camera );  `

`var sceneObj=THREE.Object3D.getObjectByName("IWantName");  `
`console.log(sceneObj.userData.someProp);  `

Comment: yes,I want to get the scene.

Comment: do you want to get the whole scene a s a 3d model ? if yes try using `scene.children()` which will give you an array  from that take only meshes ie, object.type =='mesh' and save it .

Comment: thanks.only way...use 'for in' to find mesh

Comment: go up the parent hierarchy until you find the scene object (which has no parent ...)

Answer (score -1):

There is a `getObjectByName` method for this [here in the `Object3D` class](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L354).
And [here it is also mentioned in the documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Object3D.getObjectByName).

---

### Update

Both the `getObjectByName` and the `getObjectById` methods are to find children objects inside a parent object. A scene doesn't have a parent so finding scene by id or finding scene by name doesn't make much sense...

Comment: `//some code here.....create renderer,camera;`    `var scene=new THREE.Scene();`  
`scene.name="IWantName";`  
`scene.userData.someProp="testGetObjectByName";`  
`renderer.render( scene, camera );`  

`var sceneObj=THREE.Object3D.getObjectByName("IWantName");  `  
`console.log(sceneObj.userData.someProp);  `